# How can I post link on facebook from android app using FB API?

Tags: android, facebook, share

I look all the internet and couldn't find how do I post link with a specific picture on facebook wall using fb sdk\api.

I know that this is part of the code that I need to use:

```
Facebook facebookClient = new Facebook("fb_App_id");

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", "Test Photo");
parameters.putString("link", "https://www.google.com");
parameters.putString("picture", "link to some pictrue");
facebookClient.dialog(MainActivity.this, "stream.publish", parameters, new DialogListener() {

@Override
public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onError(DialogError e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onCancel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});
```

When I try to use this code I get "Source not found" error.
I think that I'm missing the connect\verification step...

How can I make it work?

Another thing: In case I use FB SDK in my personal app that I share on Google Play and this app is FREE but has Ads on it, Is it legal to use FB SDK in my app?

Comment: have you registered your app on facebook and got App ID if yes you can use it. if no then see [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)

Comment: instead of sending three strings you can send everything in one string with formatting

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post message to facebook wall from android fb sdk always error](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3726429/post-message-to-facebook-wall-from-android-fb-sdk-always-error)

Comment: Yes I have app ID. This is not dupplicate cause I don't know what else I need to do...what "mAsyncRunner"? And is it legal to use this SDK in my app?

Comment: Are you post only text or photo and text both on facebook?

Comment: I tried to post only text but the final goal is to post\share link with a specific picture.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, different exceptions. As for the `mAsyncRunner`, it's for making [asynchronous requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ayncrequest/), you don't need to use it if you're using dialogs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found how to do it.

You need to declare this two:

```
Facebook facebookClient;    
SharedPreferences mPrefs;
```

In the onCreate function I initialize facebookClient with the facebook AppID.

**The class that lunches the facebook share must be Activity**

There are three functions that I added to the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebookClient.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public void loginToFacebook() {
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebookClient.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebookClient.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebookClient.isSessionValid()) {
        facebookClient.authorize(this, new String[] { "publish_stream" }, new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // Function to handle cancel event
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // Function to handle complete event
                // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("access_token", facebookClient.getAccessToken());
                editor.putLong("access_expires", facebookClient.getAccessExpires());
                editor.commit();

                postToWall();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError error) {
                // Function to handle error

            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                // Function to handle Facebook errors

            }

        });
    }
}

private void postToWall() {
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("name", "Battery Monitor");
    parameters.putString("link", "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ck.batterymonitor");
    parameters.putString("picture", "link to the picture");
    parameters.putString("display", "page");
    // parameters.putString("app_id", "228476323938322");

    facebookClient.dialog(MainActivity.this, "feed", parameters, new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

and at last:

```
        ImageButton facebookButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_FacebookShare);
        facebookButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                loginToFacebook();

                if (facebookClient.isSessionValid()) {
                    postToWall();
                }
            }
        });
```

It does an auto login to facebook and then displaies facebook share\post dialog.
The code was taken from this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

Comment: What happens if it doesn't auto login? Does it request the user to login and then post? What is the fallback method for not logged in?

Comment: Yes it asks the user to log in

Comment: Unfortunately, it is **deprecated** now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your problem is that you are using the [stream.publish](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/) path which got deprecated:

> Please note: We are in the process of deprecating the REST API, so if
>   you are building a new application you shouldn't use this function.
>   Instead use the Graph API and POST a Post object to the `feed`
>   connection of the User object

instead do this:

```
facebookClient.dialog(MainActivity.this, "feed", parameters, new DialogListener() {
...

});
```

Comment: Do I need some extra autorization? or something else?
Or I can use just dialog function?

Comment: I get FB windows that saies "the page requested was not found."

Comment: Oh, damn. My bad, it should be `feed` instead of `me/feed`. I'll fix it in my answer

Comment: I already found the this is the problem. Now it displaies a window in wich it asks me to login or download android facebook app that I already have...How can I avoid this window considering that I have android facebook app and I login there?

Comment: Have you gone through the authentication process with [SSO](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#enablesso)?